# Error in allocating space to an integer pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So, I want to create a function that lets the user "declare" an array, something like `int_array(a,3);` and that's my code for the function:

```
int int_array(int *p, int n)
{
   *p = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   return *p;
}
```

The thing is, I receive the following error:

> invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'.

and I don't know why. What does actually cause this error? Is it because 'n' is a simple integer and not a pointer?

Comment: change *p to p, it's a pointer being assigned to a pointer

Comment: Why are you trying to do any of this in C++? This looks like (bad) C code

Comment: You should invest in a good C++ book.

Comment: @UnholySheep any alternative for C++?

Comment: @MarioMateas definitely, however as your posted code doesn't actually do anything useful (it actually invokes *undefined behavior* after fixing the compilation error) it's hard to suggest one (as it is also unclear what that function is supposed to do)

Comment: @MarioMateas -- What made you use `malloc`?  What book did your read that advocates using `malloc` in a C++ program?  You should be using `std::vector<int> user_array(n) ` if your goal is a dynamic int array with `n` elements.

Comment: It looks like he wants the function to allocate an array and store the pointer in the variable passed as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your function is dereferencing an `int*` pointer that doesn't point to a valid `int`, and then you are trying to assign a newly allocated `int` array to the dereferenced `int`. Even if the `int` were allocated, you can't assign a pointer to a non-pointer variable, which is the error you are getting.

Try this instead:

```
int* int_array(int n)
{
    return (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

```
int *a = int_array(3);
...
free(a);
```

But, you shouldn't be using `malloc()` in C++, use `new[]` instead:

```
int* int_array(int n)
{
    return new int[n];
}
```

```
int *a = int_array(3);
...
delete[] a;
```

A better option is to use `std::unique_ptr` instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> int_array(int n)
{
    return std::make_unique<int[]>(n);
}
```

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> a = int_array(3);
...
```

Or, just get rid of this function and use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<int> a(3);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem: `*p = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`,

`*p` is an `int` and you try to assign `int *` to it. That doesn't work (atleast not the way you are attempting to do it).

Here is the fix:

```
int int_array(int *p, int n)
{
   p = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   return *p;
}
```

However, I'm afraid this leaves you with a memory leak because the pointer you allocated inside the array will never be freed.

The solution would be to return a pointer instead, or better yet (since this is supposed to be C++), return a smart pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> int_array(std::unique_ptr<int[]> &p, int n)
{
   p = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[n]);
   return p
}
```

Why even bother passing in the pointer? Just do:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> int_array(int n)
{
   return std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[n]);
}
```

Comment: You should be using `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of `std::shared_ptr<int>`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, true

Comment: you need to use the specialization of `std::unique_ptr` that is designed for arrays. I fixed it for you

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thank you